# appending list in python but get none as a result

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a csv file with several rows and columns[my csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvRVY.png),
I have written some python codes which reads one row at a time

```
import csv
import numpy as np
csvfile = 'fileone.csv'
with open(csvfile, 'r') as fin, open('filetwo', 'w') as fout:
     reader = csv.reader(fin, lineterminator='\n')
     a=[]
     b=[]
     for row in reader:
         x = np.array(row[0])
         y = np.array(row[1])
         # print x
         # print y
         if row[4]==1:
             e= a.append(x)
             f=b.append(y)
     print (a.append(x))
     # centroid = (sum(e) / len(e), sum(f) / len(f))`
```

when the speed column in that row is equal to 1,I append its longitude and latitude values to empty lists I have created,but my lists return None values,my target is to find the centroid of the longitude and latitude points which has a speed of 1,The two groups of 1's should be treated separately.How can I append the values to my list?,thanks.

Comment: You *are* appending values to the list. Methods that mutate the instance return nothing by convention; `print(a)` afterwards and ignore `e`, for example.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you should provide your comment as an answer to the question. This way it's easier to see that the question has been answered and you can get some points if it gets accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e` and `f` will always be `None` because `append()` does not return a value. Move your last append out of the `print()` and just `print(a)`